# js-dos with visual Studio to apk

Tags: javascript, android, html, visual-studio, apk

Hy,

i build with html and js-dos one page to play dos games.

```
  <canvas id="jsdos"></canvas>


<script>
    Dos(document.getElementById("jsdos"), { cycles: 'auto',
        wdosboxUrl: "./wdosbox.js",
        onprogress: (stage, total, loaded) => {
            console.log(stage, loaded * 100 / total + "%");
        },
    }).ready((fs, main) => {
      fs.extract("game.zip", "/gamedir").then(() => {
        main(["-c", "cd gamedir", "-c", "game.exe"])
      });
    });
  </script>
```

on browser it works without any problems, but when i build an apk file an install it on my smartphone the game don't load.

What could be the problem?

thx

Comment: Can you provide any browser logs? Btw, looks like a bug. Can you create issue on js-dos github page?

Comment: now i'knew the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/xxx/game/wdosbox.wasm.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

js-dos can only be host and start from a web server.

Does anybody knew a small webserver runtime for android kotlin?